# SSRS Expression Not Adding 18 Months Correctly to a Date

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, sql-date-functions, ssrs-2019

In one of my reports I have this query expression.

```
=iif(isdate(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value),iif(isdate(Fields!Extension_Expiration_Date.Value),Fields!Extension_Expiration_Date.Value,DateAdd("m",18,Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value)),"")
```

Date_of_Funding_Approval is a valid date = 04/24/2019

Extension_Expiration_Date is null

So, I am trying to add 18 months to Date_of_Funding_Approval, which should equal 10/24/2020 but it is returning 04/24/2025.

**UPDATE**

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Master Table](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [New Project ID#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [District Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Program] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [School Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Project Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Qualifying Project Costs] [money] NULL,
    [Wealth Index] [float] NULL,
    [State Financial Participation] [money] NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Means Value] [float] NULL,
    [Division Reviewed Project Size/POR] [int] NULL,
    [Primary Category] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Secondary Category] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Means Cost Center] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Rescinded] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Final] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Green Incentive SFP] [money] NULL,
    [Date Printed] [datetime] NULL,
    [Manager Area] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Grand Total SFP] [money] NULL,
    [Last_Updated] [datetime] NULL,
    [Extension Expiration Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Extension Granted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Date of Funding Approval] [datetime] NULL,
    [Project Year] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Final Cost SFP of Project] [money] NULL,
    [Project Shown in CMMS] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Final Pay Inspection Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Final Pay Inspection Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date Entered] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date Inspected] [datetime] NULL,
    [Percent Complete] [int] NULL,
    [Manager Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Date of Report] [datetime] NULL,
    [Additional Notes] [ntext] NULL,
    [LEA] [int] NULL,
    [Stat Financial Participation Notes] [ntext] NULL,
    [username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [conflict_timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Master_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Master Table] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Master Table] ([ID], [New Project ID#], [District Name], [Program], [School Name], [Project Description], [Qualifying Project Costs], [Wealth Index], [State Financial Participation], [Notes], [Means Value], [Division Reviewed Project Size/POR], [Primary Category], [Secondary Category], [Means Cost Center], [Rescinded], [Final], [Green Incentive SFP], [Date Printed], [Manager Area], [Grand Total SFP], [Last_Updated], [Extension Expiration Date], [Extension Granted], [Date of Funding Approval], [Project Year], [Final Cost SFP of Project], [Project Shown in CMMS], [Final Pay Inspection Name], [Final Pay Inspection Date], [Date Entered], [Date Inspected], [Percent Complete], [Manager Name], [Date of Report], [Additional Notes], [LEA], [Stat Financial Participation Notes], [username]) VALUES (3350, N'xxx-7207-010', N'xxx School District', N'xxx Partnership', N'-Not Specified-', N'xxx - Additions and Conversions', 7022599.0800, 0.43051886092115882, 3999237.7234, NULL, 153.58, 45726, N'Space', N'Conversion + Addition', N'xxx', NULL, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2022-02-16T07:36:47.000' AS DateTime), N'1', 3999237.7234, CAST(N'2022-02-16T07:36:47.000' AS DateTime), NULL, 0, CAST(N'2019-04-24T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Year 1', NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2019-04-29T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 7207, NULL, NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Master Table] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Master Table] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Master Ta__Means__38845C1C]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Means Value]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Master Table] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Master Ta__Divis__39788055]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Division Reviewed Project Size/POR]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Master Table] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Master Ta__Green__3A6CA48E]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Green Incentive SFP]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Master Table] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Master Ta__Exten__3B60C8C7]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Extension Granted]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Master Table] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Master Ta__Proje__3C54ED00]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Project Shown in CMMS]
GO
```

Comment: Are the date fields actually date data types? I created a small dataset to test with and it worked exactly as expected. If you need more help, I suggest you create a sample of data including the table creation code so we can reproduce exactly.

Comment: @AlanSchofield both dates are datetime nullable fields. I will ask permission if I can post the table definition and masked data.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Create script added

Comment: I plugged your script into my report and I still get the result I expected. Try just adding a simple table to the report showing funding approval date and the result of the DATEADD function and see if that looks right, then add your full expression and test again to narrow down the issue. I'm assuming the expression is on a row within a tablix(table) and not on it's own outside the tablix?

Comment: @AlanSchofield when I just set it to =adddate(...) that works. But I put the logic back in it dosen't. I even tried to use isnothing in place of the last isdate (Of course reverse the true and false) but that didn't help either.

Comment: Very strange, your original expression worked for me as expected. I'll put togther an RDL with the data you posted (minus the constraints but that won't affect anything in SSRS) and then I'll share it somewhere for you to look at.

Comment: I've shared the RDL file here https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al1Kq21dFT1ik85r-dNbDLWhC84N2Q?e=eQYX6z You'll need to connect the datasource to a valid database but it does not write anything to the database other than a #temp table so any connection will work. The dataset query is cutdown version of what you posted without the constraints etc. The link will **expire 30 June**.

Comment: @Randy Noticed instead of this part of the query being ```DateAdd("m",18,Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value)```, would using DateSerial work, like this:  ```DateSerial(Year(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value), Month(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value) + 18, Day(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DateSerial` within the query to add the 18 months, instead of `DateAdd`

It is not really any different to query in the question, except with `DataSerial`, it will allows to specify the year, month, and day components explicitly.

So the altered expression will be:

```
=iif(
  IsDate(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value),
  iif(
    IsDate(Fields!Extension_Expiration_Date.Value),
    Fields!Extension_Expiration_Date.Value,
    DateSerial(
      Year(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value),
      Month(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value) + 18,
      Day(Fields!Date_of_Funding_Approval.Value)
    )
  ),
  ""
)
```